# Detect when my webpage send pageview request with javascripts ga function before deploy my webpage

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pageviews

Over my webpage I use the google-provided `ga` function in order to send pageviews to my panel.

But how I will detect during development of the webpage's javascript when the javascript send pageview?

I am asking because it may sends more pageviews that requested especially on infinite scrolling pages and single-page applications.

I am not asking how to debug javascript but I am asking on how you can gen an indication when the page's javascript sends a pageview into the google analytics **WITHOUT**/**BEFORE** the need of deployment. In other words how I will detect over the tools that browser provides to me in order to detect when my webpage sends a pageview.

Comment: No is not is specifically for getting indication for google analytics during development when the pageview request gets sent

Comment: This still just boils down to, use debug tools.

Comment: I am telling on how to use the debug tools to detect the pageview

Comment: Yes and? TBH, this isn't rocket science. I don't think this is a bad question, I also don't think it's an overly great Q&A either. I mean good luck and all that but you haven't had an amazing epiphany that 1,000 people haven't already done in the past. My close vote still stands. May get closed, may not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the browser's developer tools (either by pressing the `F12` key or via your browsers menu) and go to `Network` tab.

Afterwards on the page network filter for `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect` each time you see that entry over the network a new pageview gets sent to the google's servers.

An alternative approach is to put `console.log` before or after `ga` function.

Comment: Did you just instantly answer your own question?

Comment: @dimitrios-desyllas I would also add checking the real-time view in the GA admin page.

Comment: [This is a self answering question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) @Jerodev